# Panda Pivot function not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using following code to pivot a table to convert entry for keys into columns. But it isn't working. ndf is showing a dataframe with (0,0) row and column. Any help?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Id": ["DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA", "DA0445EA"],
        "Port": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        "Lane": [None, None, None, None, None],
        "Key": ["start", "start", "case", "case_start", "end"],
        "Val": [0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]  
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Id', 'Port', 'Lane', 'Key', 'Val'])
ndf = df.pivot_table(columns = 'Key', values= 'Val',index=['Id', 'Port', 'Lane'], aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

| Id | Port | Lane | start | case | case_start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DA0445EA | 1 | nan | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 |

Comment: `None` is not a good value for index as `None == None` is `False`. Remove `Lane` from `index`.

Comment: Or `df['Lane'] = df['Lane'].astype(str)`